# How do I multiply integers within a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

I need to write a function that takes a list of numbers and multiplies them together. Example: [1,2,3,4,5,6] will give me 1*2*3*4*5*6. I could really use your help. This also need to work if there is a nested list. Please help! This is the code I attempted.def multiplyNums(p):
    total = 1 
    for i in p:
        if i == type(int) or type(float)
            total = total * i
        elif i == type(list):
           total2 = multiplynums()
    if p ==

```
print(total)
```

product_list([2,3,4,[2,4],2])
As you can see a portion of the code is missing but I just don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: That's a tall order.  What have you tried?

Comment: def product_list(p):
    total = 1 
    for i in p:
        total = total * i 
       
    print(total)
    
         
product_list([2,3,4,[2,4],2])

Comment: That's my code so far and it works unless there is a nested list

Comment: Also I have to use recursion

Comment: Please post some code you tried to prove you are serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from collections import Iterable

def product_of(items):
    if isinstance(items, Iterable):
        # list of items - reduce it
        total = 1
        for item in items:
            total *= product_of(item)   # <= recursive call on each item
        return total                    #    (could be a sub-list)
    else:
        # single value - return it
        return items
```

then

```
product_of([1, 2, [3, 4], 5, [6, [7, 8]]])    # => 40320
```

---

**Edit:** If you want to avoid imports, you can just replace `if isinstance(items, Iterable):` with `if isinstance(items, list):` (but then it will fail unnecessarily if `items` is a tuple, generator, set, etc).

Comment: Thanks man! Here is what I was working on is there a way to do this without importing anything.

Comment: def product_list(p):
    total = 1 
    for i in p:
        if i == type(list):
            product_list(i)
        else:
            total = total * i    
    print(total)
    
         
product_list([2,3,4,[2,4],2])